# Lenovo Yoga 11 randomly shuts down before login Ubuntu 15.10 & 15.04

Tags: boot, 15.04, shutdown, lenovo, 15.10

It always happens while booting before the login screen appears. Most confusing is, sometimes the laptop boots without any problems. The next day I have to start it like 5 times before I am able to login.

It happend with Ubuntu 15.04 as well and I hoped it will go away with 15.10 but it did not.

Before I had Linux Mint 16 installed and never experienced that error.

I suppose it is while loading some kernel module but I do not know how to read the kernel logs to debug this problem.

I appreciate any help.